# CSS different behavior external to inline

Tags: html, css, styles

I am learning about css atm, and I am trying to use a external css to style all my website. I found that if I do:

```
<ul id="menu" style="width:420px; margin:0 auto">
```

I get the result I want, but if  I do it on a external file like:

this is the css file:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
display:block;}

body {
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
background-color: #808286;
-webkit-box-pack: center;}

#container {
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 20px 0px;
display:-webkit-box;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-flex: 1; }

#top_header {
background-color: #fdd023;
padding: 20px;
border: 2px solid #49207e;}

#new_div {
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal; }

#navigation_bar {
border: 1px solid #5970B2;
padding: 0;}

#main_section   {
border: 1px solid blue;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;}

 #side_left {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 220px;
margin: 20px 0px;
padding: 30px;
background: #66CCCC;}

 #main_footer {
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
border-top: 2px solid green;}

#menu {
    width:420px; 
    margin:0 auto;}
#menu li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
display: inline;
padding: 0 8px 0px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu div {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #EAEBD8;
border: 1px solid #5970B2}

#menu div a {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: left;}
```

this is the Html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav id="navigation_bar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href=""">
                A
            </a>
                <div id="firstMenu">
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                B
            </a>

                <div id="secondMenu">
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                    <a href="#">4 </a>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                C
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                D
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                E
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </nav>
```

I get a different layout. The first centers my menu bar, and the second one give me a little of a padding. I am using Chrome, but I think I may be missing a key concept here.

Comment: Can you post your html/css here, for both working and non-working cases?  Its difficult to identify the real problem without context.

Comment: Trying to get same error with a smaller html code. Already pretty long

Comment: Posted before seeing your message :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences you are seeing are due to some other code on the page.

If a CSS rule applies (after the cascade is applied), then it doesn't matter where it came from as far as rendering is concerned.

Comment: This is the only line of code I have, which means that external gets applied first and then internal overwrites it. I suppose something after the declaration is screwing things up. I will post the rest of the code. I suppose the code has to come after and not before, right?